# Javascript aggregation issue with new server

Tags: javascript, caching, css-js-aggregation

I have a new VPS Host and have cloned my existing live site from my current VPS Host. On the new host, there is an issue with JS aggregation and I am hoping someone might recognize what this is and how to solve it.

Generally with JS aggregation set at `/admin/config/development/performance`, Javascript breaks sitewide, both front end and backend, logged in and non-logged in. I checked permissions and the JS directiory at `/sites/default/files/js/` and it seems fine, files are writing to this directory (both the JS files and the GZipped ones).

When I view the raw code of any of these files, the code is fine (not corrupt). I have also tried switching this off, clearing cache, switching back on, clearing browser cache and even deleting the directory which Drupal did and then recreated without any issue. I checked my PHP info file (5.2.17) and it shows this under `PHP Variables` `_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] - gzip,deflate,sdch` so that seems ok. However my old server's PHP info file also had `gzip,deflate,sdch` under an additional heading called "`HTTP Headers Information`".

But here is the real tell-tale, I think, when I view the code of my webpage with Chrome web inspector and look in Console, I see as many JS errors as there are aggregated files. (5 or 6 I think). The error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` If I then view the corresponding JS file, I see this:

[image]

So somehow, the aggregated JS files are turning into gibberish characters and the errors are thrown. I have spoken with my webhost and we tried some things but nothing worked. They had me put this code into .htaccess but it did not work:

```
[root@host ~]# httpd -L | grep deflate
DeflateFilterNote (mod_deflate.c)
DeflateWindowSize (mod_deflate.c)
DeflateBufferSize (mod_deflate.c)
DeflateMemLevel (mod_deflate.c)
DeflateCompressionLevel (mod_deflate.c)
```

Also I was not exactly sure where in .htaccess to put it. (under `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` perhaps?) At any rate this did nothing to help matters no matter where I tried that code. I feel like this is a bit of a needle in a haystack and might be tricky to fix but I am curious if anyone recognizes what might be going on so i can fix it.

** I should also note that litespeed Server is running on top of this so not sure if there are nay issues with that. I have not looked into this yet.

Comment: Do you have an uncommented line like `AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz` or `AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz` in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: Clive, Brilliant. That works. I also found a core issue here: http://drupal.org/node/1440534 but that did not actually fix my issue, however your code did. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept and vote up. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, glad it helped I remember that happening to me some time back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that your web server isn't sending the correct [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) or [Content-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) header for compressed files.

Adding one of these to your httpd.conf file should solve the problem:

```
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

or

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

There should be comments in your httpd.conf file that will help you determine which one's most appropriate for your situation (search for `<IfModule mime_module>` in that file if you're interested).

Comment: After thorough testing, this works great in all browsers except Chrome Canary. Chrome Production works fine. In Canary, I get this error on CSS files now: `Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.` A google search yielded a few forum posts with lots of different suggestions and explanations. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vxIgSHj3CGg

Comment: Update, it seems like I needed to add more resources to litespeed and I now have JS and CSS aggregation working in all browsers, however, I still cannot get JS gzip working. See http://drupal.org/node/1440534